# run command over ssh on originating machine

Tags: ssh, x11, desktop-environment

I have a local machine `nostromo` running an interactive cinnamon desktop on debian testing. On it, I have gnome-terminal running with an ssh terminal open to a remote machine `sulaco`. I would like to run a command in the ssh terminal such that it behaves as if I ran it from a local terminal.  For example:

```
mooseboys@nostromo:~$ ssh sulaco
mooseboys@sulaco:~$ run-on-ssh-origin xeyes
```

Given the above code, I'm looking for something like `run-on-ssh-origin` that ends up running `xeyes` in my local existing desktop environment, i.e. as if I had run it in another local gnome-terminal.

The only solution I'm aware of would be to run another `ssh` command back to `nostromo` from the `sulaco` ssh terminal:

```
mooseboys@sulaco:~$ ssh nostromo xeyes
```

This works for non-GUI commands, but for an X application it doesn't seem to create the window on the existing interactive desktop.  I'm sure there's a way to enumerate desktops and inject a command to run there, but I'm looking for something simpler and more robust.  Ideally, something like `run-on-ssh-origin` exists, but absent that, is there a way to specify e.g. that GUI applications run over SSH should use existing interactive desktops (if present)?

Comment: Alternative: Run `screen` or `tmux` on the nostromo gnome-terminal *before* you login into sulaco. Create two screens, one to login into suloca, one stays on nostromo. Switch to the nostromo screen to start local applications.

Answer (score 1):

The reason non-GUI commands run is because you are running them in a terminal chain (nostromo->sulaco->nostromo).

For X11 applications to work in that way, you just need to enable X11 forwarding on all your client and servers. Nostromo is a server here. You would then effectively be forwarding the X11 output from server2 to server1 to client which while technically possible is a bit of a drag on performance and a bit of a waste in this exact configuration

You can however simply change the display environmental variable from within the ssh command:

`ssh nostromo 'DISPLAY=:0; xeyes'`

This will redirect the X11 output to the local display `:0`, which you may or may not own and have permission to draw on. This can also have a direct impact on what kind of commands you can send based on your quotation mark requirements.

You need to know your client's local DISPLAY number. For single user this will usually be `:0`. But it can be different.